# Conditional Order By In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I have some difficulties working on a query with conditional order by.
Here is a sample data :

```
|Id | Date-In  | Date-Out |
|1  | 01/01/21 | NULL     |
|2  | 03/01/21 | NULL     |
|3  | 05/01/20 | 11/01/21 |
|3  | 12/01/21 | NULL     |
|4  | 12/12/21 | 15/01/21 |
|5  | 17/01/21 | 21/01/21 |
```

I want to sort the data like this :

```
|Id | Date-In  | Date-Out |
|5  | 17/01/21 | 21/01/21 |
|4  | 12/12/20 | 15/01/21 |
|3  | 05/01/21 | 11/01/21 |
|3  | 12/01/21 | NULL     |
|2  | 03/01/21 | NULL     |
|1  | 01/01/21 | NULL     |
```

When there is a move-out sort DESC
When there is a move-out and a move-in sort move-out DESC, move-in DESC, Id DESC (Bold) Else sort move-in DESC

Comment: If you want to format your posts, use markdown, not markup please.

Comment: Have you have any attempts here? What were they and why didn't they work?

Comment: yes i tried some queries with adding case when but not working

Comment: I tested with LAG() function and seems to work at last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this solution :

```
  SELECT  Id
      ,[move_in_date]
      ,[move_out_date]
      ,LAG(move_out_date) OVER(Partition By Id ORDER BY move_in_date) as Lag_out
  FROM MyTable
  ORDER BY isnull(move_out_date,LAG(move_out_date) OVER(Partition By Id ORDER BY move_in_date)) DESC
```

[image]
I don't know if this will work with every scenario i mentioned in my first post

Comment: And given that your output data is completely unrelated to your original sample data, it is not very helpful to anyone else reading your question. We can now see your table has rows with duplicate Id values - something that was not illustrated in your question.

Comment: in my sample i also have duplicated IDs (see Id = 3)